# What value to be passed for transaction Id in Transactional Flow api Alpakka

Tags: apache-kafka, playframework, transactions, kafka-producer-api, alpakka

Using Alpakka I want to consume records using Transactional.Source Api and produce it to another topic using Transactional.flow but documents says that we need to pass transactionId.

How should I create TransactionId for e.g. following code

````
```via(Transactional.flow(producerSettings, transactionalId))```
````

Would it be per Producer or Per Producer record in Alpakka

Answer (score 0):

> The transactional.id plays a major role in fencing out zombies. But
>   maintaining an identifier that is consistent across producer sessions
>   and also fences out zombies properly is a bit tricky.
>
> The key to fencing out zombies properly is to ensure that the input
>   topics and partitions in the read-process-write cycle is always the
>   same for a given transactional.id. If this isn’t true, then it is
>   possible for some messages to leak through the fencing provided by
>   transactions.
>
> For instance, in a distributed stream processing application, suppose
>   topic-partition tp0 was originally processed by transactional.id T0.
>   If, at some point later, it could be mapped to another producer with
>   transactional.id T1, there would be no fencing between T0 and T1. So
>   it is possible for messages from tp0 to be reprocessed, violating the
>   exactly once processing guarantee.
>
> Practically, one would either have to store the mapping between input
>   partitions and transactional.ids in an external store, or have some
>   static encoding of it. Kafka Streams opts for the latter approach to
>   solve this problem. How transactions perform, and how to tune them

[Transactions in Apache Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/)